# Read from file and display using Json.net

Tags: c#, android, json

I'm writing android app.

Have Json that I Writing to file using JSON.NET

How I can read from file and display to TextView?

Writing:

```
var url3 = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
        string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        using (var wc = new WebClient ()) {
            // Download the json data
            var jsonData = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync (new Uri (url3));

            // Save the json data
            File.WriteAllText (System.IO.Path.Combine (path, "myfile.txt"), jsonData);
        }
```

Now I display using default json library

Code:

```
 private void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue json)
    {



        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);
        productname.Click += delegate {
            var intent404 = new Intent (this, typeof(SoupesDetailActivity1));

            StartActivity (intent404);
        };

            JsonValue firstitem = json [81];

            productname.Text = firstitem ["post_title"];
            price.Text = firstitem ["price"] + " грн";
            weight.Text = firstitem ["weight"] + "г";




    }
```

Comment: What is the value of the "json" parameter in your ParseAndDisplay1 method ? What is the exact error ?

Comment: json [81]; you about this? @Cubi

Comment: I don't have errors, I don't know how to read information from file an display to TextView.

I need to read json[81].
[link](http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts&arr) - values.

Maybe I need to use StreamReader? @Cubi

Answer (score 0):

As of using Json in java I have read the stored data from a json object like this.

1)read the file using streams

2)store the result in String=string_read

3)get the JSONObjects which u have stored through parsing string Via JsonTokener
JSONArray array=(JSONArray)new JSONTokener(string_read).nextValue();

4)parse the array using for loop

for(JSONObject jsonobj:array)

{

jsonobj.getString("Key_given");//store it in a variable and use it

}

Comment: I don't know c# ,so sorry if it's not helpful